# Jaydata cancel pending changes

Tags: jaydata

Trying to cancel Entity changes it some situation.

Breeze for example has a `cancelChanges()` function on the EntityContext.

What would it be in JayData ?

I tried at the entity level with `entityInstance.resetChanges()` but no go...

Answer (score 1):

Try to nest your code in a transaction and if something happens rollback 
http://jaydata.org/blog/database-transaction-handling-in-jaydata

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly I am doing some heavy sharing of my entities accross several controllers and this would become a pain to implement on each change to the entity's property. If I knew this I could have gone with it but my current design doesnt allow me to do this now. Since JD appears to have an EntityState Manager, I was hopping on a more abstract solution than falling back to tx handling. +1 for the idea though!

Comment: wished I would've been of a better help :)